# CollectionType with multiple entity type + Ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem creating a form by including a formType that are 2 related entities and that must be combined with a CollectionType.

I use the library jquery.collection for CollectionType ( http://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/ )

## My entities

**Product**

```
namespace BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BBW\ProductBundle\Repository\Product\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{

    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup", inversedBy="products", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_join_attribute_group")
     */
    private $attributeGroups;

    /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute", inversedBy="products", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_join_attribute")
     */
    private $attributes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attributeGroups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->attributes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add attributeGroup
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup $attributeGroup
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addAttributeGroup(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup $attributeGroup)
    {
        $this->attributeGroups[] = $attributeGroup;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove attributeGroup
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup $attributeGroup
     */
    public function removeAttributeGroup(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup $attributeGroup)
    {
        $this->attributeGroups->removeElement($attributeGroup);
    }

    /**
     * Get attributeGroups
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAttributeGroups()
    {
        return $this->attributeGroups;
    }

    /**
     * Add attribute
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute $attribute
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addAttribute(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute $attribute)
    {
        $this->attributes[] = $attribute;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove attribute
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute $attribute
     */
    public function removeAttribute(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute $attribute)
    {
        $this->attributes->removeElement($attribute);
    }

    /**
     * Get attributes
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }
}
```

**AttributeGroup**

```
namespace BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * AttributeGroup
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_attribute_group")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BBW\ProductBundle\Repository\Attribute\AttributeGroupRepository")
 */
class AttributeGroup
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute", mappedBy="attributeGroup", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attribute_id")
     */
    private $attributes ;

    /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product", mappedBy="attributeGroups", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attributes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add attribute
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute $attribute
     *
     * @return AttributeGroup
     */
    public function addAttribute(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute $attribute)
    {
        $this->attributes[] = $attribute;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove attribute
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute $attribute
     */
    public function removeAttribute(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute $attribute)
    {
        $this->attributes->removeElement($attribute);
    }

    /**
     * Get attributes
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }


    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product $product
     *
     * @return AttributeGroup
     */
    public function addProduct(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product $product
     */
    public function removeProduct(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
}
```

**Attributes**

```
namespace BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * Attribute
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_attribute")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BBW\ProductBundle\Repository\Attribute\AttributeRepository")
 */
class Attribute
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup", inversedBy="attributes", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attribute_group_id")
     */
    private $attributeGroup ;

    /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product", mappedBy="attributes", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set attributeGroup
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup $attributeGroup
     *
     * @return Attribute
     */
    public function setAttributeGroup(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup $attributeGroup = null)
    {
        $this->attributeGroup = $attributeGroup;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get attributeGroup
     *
     * @return \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup
     */
    public function getAttributeGroup()
    {
        return $this->attributeGroup;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product $product
     *
     * @return Attribute
     */
    public function addProduct(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param \BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product $product
     */
    public function removeProduct(\BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

My product must belong to an attribute group and must contain attributes. I have a relationship between my AttributeGroup entity and a Relationship with Attribute.

My Entity AttributeGroup has a relationship with Attribute (functional).

## Form Types

In my form I have a CollectionType with another formType as entry_type I have created with two entity types (AttributeGroups / Attributes)

**FormType for product**

```
namespace BBW\ProductBundle\Form\Product;

use A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\Form\Type\TranslationsType;
use BBW\CoreBundle\FormTypes\SwitchType;
use BBW\MediaBundle\Transformers\MediaTransformer;
use BBW\ProductBundle\Form\Attribute\Type\AttributeType;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductEditType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $locale = $options['int_service'];

        $builder
            ->add('attributes', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => AttributeType::class,
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'label' => false
                ),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'attributes-selector'
                ),
            ))
            ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product',
            'int_service' => ['fr'],
            'translation_domain' => 'ProductBundle'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'bbw_productbundle_edit_product';
    }
}
```

**AttributeType**

```
/**
 * Form Type: Fields add in product edit form
 */

namespace BBW\ProductBundle\Form\Attribute\Type;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AttributeType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('attributeGroups', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\AttributeGroup',
                'choice_label' => 'translate.name',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'choiceAttributeGroup'
                ),
            ))
            ->add('attributes', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Attribute\Attribute',
                'choice_label' => 'translate.name',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'choiceAttributes'
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product',
            'int_service' => ['fr'],
            'translation_domain' => 'ProductBundle'
        ));
    }

}
```

**Explanation**

The two entities (AttributeGroups / Attributes) are two linked drop-down lists. When I select a group, I must display the data of this group in the second drop-down list. This part works well. I can duplicate as much as I want (with the CollectionType).

**First problem** when i submit the form:

"Could not determine access type for property "attributeGroups" ".

**Second problem** when i set "mapped => false" in my two entities:

"Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product#$attributes", got "BBW\ProductBundle\Entity\Product\Product" instead."

**Screeshoots dump/form**

[image: Screen for my collection type with two related dropdown]
[image: Screen for my dump when i submit]

**Conclusion**

I think my problem is a mapping problem, having tested a lot of code and explanation on the symfony doc or other site, I could not solve my problem. If anyone could help me out and explain the good work of a collectionType with 2 entity and if that is possible. If you have examples of codes I am taker too.

Thank you in advance for your help.